# Prevent copy-construction with make_shared

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have a manager class that allow clients to add components through two methods: one with no argument that default-construct the component and another one that takes an rvalue (which should allow client to use a custom constructor of the component).

Here's the code I came up with:

```cpp
template <class TComponent>
std::shared_ptr<TComponent> AddComponent()
{
    return AddComponent(TComponent{ this });
}

template <class TComponent>
std::shared_ptr<TComponent> AddComponent(const TComponent &&obj)
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<TComponent>(obj);
    vec.push_back(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

The problem I have is that *std::make_shared* always copy-constructs the object. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? 
I read about perfect forwarding but it doesn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read about perfect forwarding but it doesn't seem to help here.

I don't see why it wouldn't.

Simply remove the const to make move construction possible, and add `std::forward`:

```
template <class TComponent>
std::shared_ptr<TComponent> AddComponent(TComponent &&obj)
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<TComponent>(std::forward<TComponent>(obj));
    vec.push_back(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Now, rvalues will be moved. Lvalues will be copied which you cannot avoid.

Comment: Alright, that's what I tried to apply perfect forwarding. So am I mistaken when thinking that `TestComponent{&manager, 0.5f}` in `manager.AddComponent<TestComponent>(TestComponent{&manager, 0.5f})` is an rvalue? With this line and the code in your post above, the copy constructor is still called from make_shared.

Comment: @Aer yes, that's an rvalue. The copy constructor would be called in case `TestComponent` class happens to not be movable. Did you check that? In any case, I recommend creating a [mcve].

Comment: You're right! The problem was in my example: I had implemented a copy-constructor and no move-constructor. Looking up the rules of move-constructor generation reminded me that the compiler generated it only if there were no user-declared copy constructor. Kind of silly on my part! Thanks for your help.